# Cropper JS fixed Width and Height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, cropperjs, image-cropper

The specified height and width are not used. In addition, the crop window is resizable. I want to have a fixed width and height of 160 pixels.

```
cropper = new Cropper(ProfileImageToCrop, {
            aspectRatio: 1/1,
            minCanvasWidth: 160,
            minCanvasHeight: 160,
            //   dragMode: "move",
            data:{ //define cropbox size
                width: 160,
                height:  160,
            },
            cropBoxResizable: false});
```